# How to fix the error "cannot read property then of undefined" react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i want to return the promise that gets resolved when the first poll finishes...

I have a start_polling method and i want to modify it such that it returns a promise that gets resolved when the items_promise gets resolved...i am not sure how to do it.

What i have tried?

i have created a promise in start_polling method that gets resolved when the item_promise_finish() is executed in then method of items_promise.

Once this promise in start_polling is resolved then i call handle_location method.

It works fine but sometimes i get error cannot read property then of undefined.

How can i fix it.

below is the code,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {state, props} = this;
    const current_id = props.item && props.item.id;
    const prev_id = prevProps.item && prevProps.item.id;
    if (current_id !== prev_id) {
        this.stop_polling();
        this.setState(this.get_initial_state(), () => {
            this.start_polling();
        });
     } else {
         const prev_poll = this.should_poll(prevProps, prevState);
         const next_poll = this.should_poll(props, state);
         if (prev_poll !== next_poll) {
             if (next_poll) {
                 this.start_polling();
             } else {
                this.stop_polling();
         }
    }
    if (this.props.location.search) {
        this.start_polling().then(() => {
            this.handle_location();
        })
}

start_polling = () => {
    if (this.should_poll(this.props, this.state)) {
        this.poll();
        return new Promise((resolve) => { 
            this.item_promise_finish=resolve; 
        });
    }
};

poll = () => {
    let still_polling = true;
    if (this.cancel_poll_request) {
        this.cancel_poll_request();
    }
});

const items_promise = client.get_items(this.props.item.id,  
cancel_poll_promise);
items_promise.then((request) => {
    const next_items = [];
    let something_changed = false;
    for (const new_item of request.response) {
        const old_item = this.state.items.find(
            old_item =>
                old_item.id === new_item.id);
        if (old_item) {
            next_items.push(old_item);
        } else {
            something_changed = true;
            next_items.push(new_item);
        }
    }

    if (something_changed) {
        const next_state = {items: next_items};
        this.setState(next_state);
    }
}).then(() => {
    if (still_polling) {
        this.poll_timeout = setTimeout(this.poll, 100s);
    }
    this.item_promise_finish();
}).catch(this.props.notifications.request_error);
};
```

Could someone let me know where i am going wrong or what to be done to fix this. thanks.

Comment: `start_polling` returns `undefined` if `this.should_poll(this.props, this.state)` returns `false`, which means it's not always returning a Promise, which you assumed it would in your code.

Comment: hm so how could it be solved. thanks.

Comment: That's in your hand now. You know the source of the problem, how it should be changed depends on what you're trying to do...

Comment: thanks solved the problem.